# Bash: ansi color when reading input from user

Tags: bash, input, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

When using read command to get user input like the following

```
read -p "[WARN] Text.. [Y/N]" choice
```

Is it possible to assign an ANSI color to the warning text, like in echo command?

```
WARN='\033[0;33m'
RESET='\e[0m'

echo -e "${WARN}Some warning message${RESET}"
```

Comment: Why not use `echo` for the prompt (you can use `-n`  to not add the newline), and `read` to read the choice (without prompt)?

Answer (score 0):

As [Some programmer dude mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575993/bash-ansi-color-when-reading-input-from-user#comment92087327_52575993), you can simply

```
warn='\033[0;33m'
reset='\e[0m'

echo -e -n "${warn}[WARN] Text.. [Y/N] ${reset}"
read choice
```

Comment: I suggest to add option `-n` to `echo` to avoid newline.

Comment: why mix `\033` and `\e`? (They're both acceptable, just styling preferences)

Comment: Just copied OP's code for that.